How to choose colors that are friendly to color deficient people?
I need to prepare a Mathematica notebook for presentation,
in which I want to use several different colors in order to
highlight some key symbols.
To make the presentation accesible to color deficient people,
I would like to follow the guidelines of
Qualitative Colour Schemes or
Color Universal Design.
I also found a similar question in SE, but it does not directly answer the following
Question: Given an integer ncol (say, between 2 and 6)
as input, how can I generate an appropriate (hopefully random)
list of ncol different colors as output?
The main part of my presentation is given in black letters
on white background (as is the default style of MMA notebook), and I'm planning to use the syntax
Highlighted["some word", Background -> somecolor].
I know MMA's ColorData[k, "ColorList"] might be used
for this purpose, but I cannot do it myself.
Any suggestions are welcome.

Minor PC point:  such people are called "color deficient," not "color blind" because they are not blind to color... they just see colors differently and usually with less overall discrimination.

@DavidG.Stork Thank you very much for the comment. I changed the title.

I sampled the diverging colour scheme from Qualitative Colour Schemes. (Unfortunately, it's not random.)
Clear["`*"]
rainbowColor[x_] := 
 Module[{ColorData = {{167, 120, 180}, {155, 98, 167}, {140, 78, 
      153}, {111, 76, 155}, {96, 89, 169}, {85, 104, 184}, {78, 121, 
      197}, {77, 138, 198}, {78, 150, 188}, {84, 158, 179}, {89, 165, 
      169}, {96, 171, 158}, {105, 177, 144}, {119, 183, 125}, {140, 
      188, 104}, {166, 190, 84}, {190, 188, 72}, {209, 181, 65}, {221,
       170, 60}, {228, 156, 57}, {231, 140, 53}, {230, 121, 50}, {228,
       99, 45}, {223, 72, 40}, {218, 34, 34}}, l},
  l = Length[ColorData] - 1;
  RGBColor[{Interpolation[ColorData[[;; , 1]]][1 + l  x],
     Interpolation[ColorData[[;; , 2]]][1 + l  x],
     Interpolation[ColorData[[;; , 3]]][1 + l  x]}/256]]
iridescentColor[x_] := 
 Module[{ColorData = {{254, 251, 233}, {252, 247, 213}, {245, 243, 
      193}, {234, 240, 181}, {221, 236, 191}, {208, 231, 202}, {194, 
      227, 210}, {181, 221, 216}, {168, 216, 220}, {155, 210, 
      225}, {141, 203, 228}, {129, 196, 231}, {123, 188, 231}, {126, 
      178, 228}, {136, 165, 221}, {147, 152, 210}, {155, 138, 
      196}, {157, 125, 178}, {154, 112, 158}, {144, 99, 136}}, l},
  l = Length[ColorData] - 1;
  RGBColor[{Interpolation[ColorData[[;; , 1]]][1 + l  x],
     Interpolation[ColorData[[;; , 2]]][1 + l  x],
     Interpolation[ColorData[[;; , 3]]][1 + l  x]}/256]]

colorlist[scheme_, ncol_?(IntegerQ[#] && # > 1 &)] := 
 scheme /@ Subdivide[ncol - 1]
colorlist[rainbowColor, 3]
colorlist[iridescentColor, 8]


In fact I think it would be better to choose a few colors in the qualitative colour scheme.

Thank you very much for your answer, especially taking your time to preparing the color data. Yes, it may be easy and safe to choose from a suitable color list. But which colors are hard to distinguish may vary between individuals (?), it will be nice if I can change colors randomly.
